# SQL - Can a single transaction be split into multiple smaller sql files?

Tags: sql

I have a huge SQL script that I want to split into several smaller scripts. Problem is, this huge sql script is one single transaction which I want to rollback if any errors occur.

How can I go about this?

Comment: It would help if you add a tag for the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Use Stored Procedures to break up the logical “Sub Transactions”.
Use Named Transactions  like this …

```
BEGIN TRAN  MySubTranOuter  

BEGIN TRAN PointA

EXEC spMyPartialCodeSubStep1 @Param1  @Param2 

COMMIT  TRAN PointA

BEGIN TRAN PointB

EXEC spMyPartialCodeSubStep2 @Param1  @Param2 

COMMMIT  TRAN PointB

COMMIT TRAN MySubTranOuter
```

If it is so big to start with that you want to break it up then I would step back right now and look at how you can break it up into 3 or 4 individual transactions.  Similar to a Queue or Status check where you move the transaction through each step via an external caller or service.

If you think it is too big now it might really big too big and you need to rethink it. I would be concerned about logically locking too many tables if it is that big.